# Magento 2 : Where Put External Dependency?

Tags: magento2, module, composer, dependency

I'm developing module to call REST API and I want to use an external package via composer. In which composer.json I should put dependency? In composer.json in root directory or composer.json in module directory?

Answer (score 1):

If your module has a `composer.json`, this probably means that you installed it via composer. In that case:

- you might want to reuse that module elsewhere
- you have to add the dependency to the module composer.json
- then run `composer update your/module --with-dependencies` in the project root

**BUT** if the module sits in `app/code` and has a `composer.json` just to satisfy Magentos package inspection, you will have to add any additional dependencies to the project's `composer.json`. You might want to add it to the module's file as well for documentation purpose, but if the module has not been installed via composer, it won't have any effect.